# Timetable assign slot and room to classes

Tags: optimization, branch-and-bound

I just wondering if there are other ways to solve this problem (like Branch and bound) and some explanation for how the algorithm works.
Problems: There are  classes 1,2,…, that need to be scheduled. Each class  has () as the number of periods and () as the teacher assigned to teach that class and () as the number of students in the class. There are  classrooms 1,2,…,, where () is the number of seats in room . There are 5 days in the week (from Monday to Thursday), each day is divided into 12 periods (6 morning periods and 6 afternoon periods). The periods of each day are numbered from 1 to 60. Make a schedule (determine days, periods and rooms assigned to each class):

- Two classes with the same teacher must have separate schedules
- The number of students in each class must be less than or equal to the number of seats in the classroom
- The number of classes scheduled is the largest

I have tried the Greedy algorithms like this:

```
class Class:
    constructor(ID, t, g, s)
        self.ID = ID
        self.t = t
        self.g = g
        self.s = s
        self.rooms = []
        self.sol = []

class Room:
    constructor(ID, capacity)
        self.ID = ID
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.last_False = 1
        self.used = {slot: False for slot in range(1, 61)}

class Teacher:
    constructor(ID)
        self.ID = ID
        self.used = {slot: False for slot in range(1, 61)}

function import_data()
    classes = []
    teachers = {}
    rooms = []

    N, M = read integers from input
    for i = 1 to N do
        t, g, s = read integers from input
        class = new Class(i, t, g, s)
        classes.append(class)
        if g not in teachers.keys() then
            teacher = new Teacher(g)
            teachers[g] = teacher

    temp = read list of integers from input
    for i = 1 to M do
        capacity = temp[i-1]
        room = new Room(i, capacity)
        rooms.append(room)

    return classes, teachers, rooms

class Solver:
    constructor(classes, teachers, rooms)
        self.classes = classes
        self.teachers = teachers
        self.rooms = rooms

    function find_possible_rooms()
        for each class in classes do
            for each room in rooms do
                if room.capacity >= class.s then
                    class.rooms.append(room)

    function solve()
        find_possible_rooms()
        sort classes by t in ascending order
        removed_classes = []
        for each class in classes do
            for slot = 1 to 60 do
                if slot + class.t > 61 then
                    continue

                found_slot = true
                for each room in class.rooms do
                    for period = slot to (slot + class.t - 1) do
                        if room.used[period] or teachers[class.g].used[period] then
                            found_slot = false
                            exit inner loop
                    if found_slot then
                        class.sol = [slot, room.ID]
                        for period = slot to (slot + class.t - 1) do
                            room.used[period] = true
                            teachers[class.g].used[period] = true
                        room.last_False = slot + class.t
                        exit outer loop

                if not found_slot then
                    removed_classes.append(class)

        for each class in removed_classes do
            classes.remove(class)

        sort classes by ID in ascending order

    function print_sol()
        print length of classes
        for each class in classes do
            print class.ID, class.sol

function main()
    classes, teachers, rooms = import_data()
    solver = new Solver(classes, teachers, rooms)
    solver.solve()
    solver.print_sol()

main()
```

And also tried with Local Search like this:

```
class Class:
    constructor(ID, t, g, s)
        self.ID = ID
        self.t = t
        self.g = g
        self.s = s
        self.rooms = []
        self.sol = []

class Room:
    constructor(ID, capacity)
        self.ID = ID
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.last_False = 1
        self.used = {slot: False for slot in range(1, 61)}

class Teacher:
    constructor(ID)
        self.ID = ID
        self.used = {slot: False for slot in range(1, 61)}

function import_data()
    classes = []
    teachers = {}
    rooms = []

    N, M = read integers from input
    for i = 1 to N do
        t, g, s = read integers from input
        class = new Class(i, t, g, s)
        classes.append(class)
        if g not in teachers.keys() then
            teacher = new Teacher(g)
            teachers[g] = teacher

    temp = read list of integers from input
    for i = 1 to M do
        capacity = temp[i-1]
        room = new Room(i, capacity)
        rooms.append(room)

    return classes, teachers, rooms

class Solver:
    constructor(classes, teachers, rooms)
        self.classes = classes
        self.teachers = teachers
        self.rooms = rooms

    function find_possible_rooms()
        for each class in classes do
            for each room in rooms do
                if room.capacity >= class.s then
                    class.rooms.append(room)

    function initial_solution()
        find_possible_rooms()
        sort classes by t in ascending order
        removed_classes = []
        for each class in classes do
            for slot = 1 to 60 do
                if slot + class.t > 61 then
                    continue

                found_slot = true
                for each room in class.rooms do
                    for period = slot to (slot + class.t - 1) do
                        if room.used[period] or teachers[class.g].used[period] then
                            found_slot = false
                            exit inner loop
                    if found_slot then
                        class.sol = [slot, room.ID]
                        for period = slot to (slot + class.t - 1) do
                            room.used[period] = true
                            teachers[class.g].used[period] = true
                        room.last_False = slot + class.t
                        exit outer loop

                if not found_slot then
                    removed_classes.append(class)

        for each class in removed_classes do
            classes.remove(class)

        sort classes by ID in ascending order

    function evaluate_solution()
        score = 0
        for each class in classes do
            slot, roomID = class.sol
            score += slot + roomID
        return score

    function local_search()
        best_score = evaluate_solution()
        best_solution = copy of classes

        for each class in classes do
            original_sol = class.sol
            for each room in class.rooms do
                if room.ID == original_sol[1] then
                    continue

                class.sol[1] = original_sol[1]
                room.used[original_sol[0]] = false
                teachers[class.g].used[original_sol[0]] = false

                for period = original_sol[0] to (original_sol[0] + class.t - 1) do
                    room.used[period] = false
                    teachers[class.g].used[period] = false

                if room.capacity >= class.s then
                    class.sol[1] = room.ID
                    for period = class.sol[0] to (class.sol[0] + class.t - 1) do
                        room.used[period] = true
                        teachers[class.g].used[period] = true

                    score = evaluate_solution()
                    if score < best_score then
                        best_score = score
                        best_solution = copy of classes

                room.used[original_sol[0]] = true
                teachers[class.g].used[original_sol[0]] = true

                for period = original_sol[0] to (original_sol[0] + class.t - 1) do
                    room.used[period] = true
                    teachers[class.g].used[period] = true

        classes = copy of best_solution

    function metaheuristic()
        iterations = 100
        best_score = evaluate_solution()
        best_solution = copy of classes

        for i = 1 to iterations do
            local_search()
            score = evaluate_solution()
            if score < best_score then
                best_score = score
                best_solution = copy of classes

        classes = copy of best_solution

    function print_sol()
        print lengthof classes
        for each class in classes do
            print class.ID, class.sol

function main()
    classes, teachers, rooms = import_data()
    solver = new Solver(classes, teachers, rooms)
    solver.initial_solution()
    solver.metaheuristic()
    solver.print_sol()

main()
```

I'm curious about the Branch & Bound. I've tried some google search and chat gpt but I haven't found anything useful to me yet. Can someone explain how Branch & Bound works on this problem for me ? Thanks alot.